# How can I set negative margin for background URL image in using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to fit a background URL into a seamless pattern using just CSS/HTML.

To get this done, I am trying to apply a property like margin (negative) to make background URL image overlap each other on repeat.

I am using a DIV element right now, applying a negative margin on this element itself just affect the element, not the background URL image.

Any ideas how to solve this?

> Current code on HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

> Current code on CSS

```
<style>
    .bg{
        background: url('./pattern.png');
        background-size: 600px;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

Render result of the code above:

[image: Render result of the code above]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not updating the PNG to make it look like a real pattern ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple background-images and then use their position to make them overlap. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

```css
.bg {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/600'), url('https://picsum.photos/600');
  background-size: 600px;
  background-position: -100px bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: I decided to apply your solution to the .bg::before, so I can change and manipulate the background image without changing the flow of the document ;)
Thanks, Dominik!